# How to keep window inactive on simulated clicks?

Tags: c++, winapi, click, window

I made a program in C++ that simulates clicks on an inactive window using:

```
PostMessage (z, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0,MAKELONG(t.left+x,t.top+y));
```

But whenever it makes a click it activates the window and the window moves to the top.

Is there a way I can make the window stay inactive or another way to click it?

I used `SetWindowPos(z , HWND_BOTTOM,....)` to make that window be at the bottom of the z-order list but it still activates.

EDIT: the window is a game console

Comment: This is normal of course, that also happens when you use the mouse to click on a window.  No, you can't change that behavior if you don't have the source of the program.

Comment: I am also trying to do something like that. But if he has the source code? What has he to do?:)

Comment: on other windows (folder, notepad) it does not activate them

Comment: i havent done this myself but i reckon this would help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#zorder

Comment: I know about z-order i used SetWindowPos(z , HWND_BOTTOM,....) to make that window to be at the bottom of the z-order list but it still activate.

Comment: Use GetActiveWindow(), send your click, then SetActiveWindow(), then it won't be active anymore. - Actually Get/SetForegroundWindow might be more of what you're after.

Comment: Also tried that but it dont look good. The window still pop-up and then it goes to background.

Comment: If you control the target window, you can handle the `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` message to prevent the window from activating (by returning `MA_NOACTIVATE`).

Comment: i've heard about mouseactivate and i searched a example because idk how to use it if you can show me how to use that function it would be great!

Comment: @JonathanPotter beat me to it.

Comment: To synthesize input `PostMessage` is the wrong tool. Use [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx) instead. Expanding on what Jonathan Potter suggested you can take control over a window you do not own, even if you do not have the source code. You first have to get your code into the target process (using a hook for example). Next step would be to have that code subclass the target window. Once your WndProc is in control you can simply ignore `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` messages. Note however that this is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching from `PostMessage` to [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and see if you get the same effect.